# I am getting error message running django-admin. I already installed django

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner at Django. I installed Django in `PyCharm` but I'm not able to make run the command

```
> django-admin startproject <name>.
```

When I run this command I got

> 'django-admin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

```
> python3 -m django --version
> django-admin.py version
> ./manage.py --version

> pip install django
Requirement already satisfied:

> django-admin version
'django-admin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! This error might depend on the way that you installed Python. Can you show us the result of `echo %PATH%`? (The path shows a list of directories to look for an executable when you don't provide a path on the command line.) It could be that `django-admin` was installed correctly, but that Windows is unaware of where that is.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following from terminal (where you are trying to run `django-admin startproject`):

```
python3 -m pip install django
```

**Edit:**

For further investigation you should look into the PyCharm setting [Configuring Python Interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html) to find out if there is a specific 
virtual environment for the project where you installed Django. Then you would need to activate that environment in the terminal.